# Interpolating dataset to achieve continuous time intervals?

Tags: r, interpolation

I have my original data set arranged with respect to time in a non-uniform manner. How can I convert it in uniform time intervals (lets say in  10 mins continuous interval)?

```
 Date   Time  Lat  Long
1-1-08 23.00  12   13
1-1-08 23.20  14   18
1-1-08 23.50  20   14
2-1-08 00.00  16   17
2-1-08 00.30  13   20
2-1-08 00.50  18   19
2-1-08 01.30  11   21
2-1-08 01.40  15   18
```

Comment: `?approxfun`, `?as.POSIXct`, `?paste0`, `?cut.POSIXt`

Comment: Just reading `?approx` - I didn't realise it can't extend beyond the bounds of the original inputs and only interpolated between each pair of points. Well, I learnt something today

Comment: @thelatemail yes, I only want to interpolate for now just to acheive the uniformness in my data set.. I tried using xspline() in this. I knid of getting it correct.